# On the inequality $a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}<d^{1/n}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

For the inequality $a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}<d^{1/n}$, 
 We want to find numbers like $a$ and $d$ for a given $b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}$ with following condition:

$(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})-a^{1/n}<1$

$d^{1/n}-(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})<1$

Condition for solving can be; if $b^{1/n}$ or $c^{1/n}$ are irrational then $b$ or $c$ must be  such that we can construct  a term like a multiple of number $(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})$ in expansion of $(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})^n$, thereby construct a polynomial like f(x), where $x= b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}$ . The resulting polynomial  $f(x)=x^n + Ax+C$ helps us to find lower and upper bound of inequality or prove an equality of this form.For example :

Prove that $43^{1/3}<3^{1/3}+9^{1/3}<44^{1/3}$ :

Solution:

$(3^{1/3}+9^{1/3})^3=9(3^{1/3}+9^{1/3})+12$

Hence resulting polynomial is $f(x)=x^3-9x-12$, where  $(3^{1/3}+9^{1/3})$ is one of its real roots.We can write:

$f(x)=x^3-9x-12=x(x^2-9)-12$

therefor  $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x> 3$. Now we can check lower and upper bounds; putting their values in $f(x)$ we find that $f(43^{1/3})<0$ and $f(44^{1/3}>0$ , therefore:

$43^{1/3}<3^{1/3}+9^{1/3}<44^{1/3}$

$(3^{1/3}+9^{1/3})-43^{1/3}≈0.3$

and:

$44^{1/3}-(3^{1/3}+9^{1/3})≈0.01$

With  condition mentioned above we can construct many inequality such as 
 $a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}<d^{1/n}$. For example we find lower and upper bound for $\sqrt 4+\sqrt 5$:

$(\sqrt 4 +\sqrt 5)^2= 4(\sqrt 4+\sqrt 5)-1 $

So resulting polynomial is $f(x)=x^2-4x-1=x(x-4)-1$
we can see that for $x≤ 4$ , $f(x)<0$ and for $x≥5$,  $f(x)>0$ and conclude that :

Lower bound=$\sqrt {16}$; $\sqrt 4 +\sqrt 5-\sqrt {16}≈0.236$

upper bound=$\sqrt {25}$; $\sqrt {25}- (\sqrt 4+\sqrt 5)≈0.764$

and we have : $\sqrt {16}<\sqrt 4+\sqrt 5<\sqrt{ 25}$

What makes it difficult is  when a and d must be  two consecutive numbers or two primes. It is even more difficult if we have  lower and upper bounds  $a^{1/n}$ and $d^{1/n}$ and we must find  $b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}$.

So I have following questions:

1): are there more consecutive  numbers such as 43 and 44 for this inequality?

2): are there primes for lower and upper bound for this inequality?

Comment: Do you mean a and d in the first line?

Comment: yes. I edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand why you picked $\sqrt{16}$ and $\sqrt{25}$ for the bounds in the $\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{5}$ example rather than $\sqrt{17}$ and $\sqrt{18}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, good point, $\sqrt {18}$ is more reasonable , also $\sqrt 17$ is accetable. may be I had to say minimum difference rather than just 'less than one'

Comment: @DanielFischer, Hence it seems number of consecutive numbers for a and d can be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})^n$ is an integer we can always find consecutive integers $a$ and $d$ such that $a<(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})^n<d$ and then

$$a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}<d^{1/n}.$$

For $a$ and $d$ to be primes we either have $a=2$ or both $a$ and $d$ are odd. For minimal differences, the latter case can only occur if $(b^{1/n}+c^{1/n})^n$ is an integer. So, for example, we have 
$$191^{1/2}<3^{1/2}+147^{1/2}<193^{1/2}.$$
.